# An inequality about dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V=U\oplus W$ and $E$ is an arbitrary subspace of $V$. I want to show that

$$2\dim E - \dim V \leq \dim((U\cap E)\oplus(W\cap E))\leq \dim E$$

I can prove that $2\dim E - \dim V \leq \dim E$ but I have no idea about proving $\dim((U\cap E)\oplus(W\cap E))$

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ be a basis for $U \cap E$ and $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ be a basis for $W \cap E$. Check that $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\} \cup \{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ is  basis for $E$. Now $2 \dim (E)=2(n+m) \leq n+m+\dim V$ because $n+m \leq \dim V$.

The right hand inequality is obvious since $(U\cap E)\bigoplus(W\cap E)\subseteq E$.